# Create Panoramic Mode React Native

Tags: react-native, camera, geometry, blob

How would I go about emulating the pano mode on IOS with react native? My use case is that I need to be able to read the text (with an OCR) from a 180 degree surface (think about reading the text of a coke bottle). I see several alternatives:

1. Have the user take two or three pictures. There are two issues with this: (a) it's not particularly user friendly, and (b) something could appear in both photo A and photo B or in just A or just B. Merging the results seems messy.
2. Take multiple photos as above, but merge them programmatically. This sounds like what underlies panoramic pictures already. Since the photo isn't going to be used outside of back end activities, it doesn't have to look nice. The difficulty is that I have not come across any libraries that help with this or guidance about how I would do this.
3. Take a video. Extract frames which gives us the appropriate information. We can improve performance by not really taking video, but rather timing it to take pictures at preset intervals.

I am using "react-native-camera" library, but below I provided a snippet to just show my thought process. I am not interested in syntax, but rather a solution.

```
takePic() {
    let self = this;
    self.takePicture()
    .then(pic1 => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.takePicture
                .then(pic2 => {
                    self.mergePictures(pic1, pic2); // what would this 
                })
        }, 500);

    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
merge(pic1, pic2) {
    // find common boundary?
    // merge along common boundary
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the technical side, I sent both images to a python lambda function for processing. I used OpenCV to patch the images together and translate the combined image through.

The front end takes two pictures, one when the person initially presses the button and one when they release. I would like to eventually minimize the images and add them to a horizontal bar across the middle (more or less like IOS does). But the above solution fits my case and is performant enough for the project.

If anyone is interested in the particular code, I will be happy to edit the answer with more details.

Comment: Please share more details on your implementation

Comment: yes please @Matty kindly share more details

Comment: @Matty Can you please elaborate your answer?